# Paypal - Login with PIN

Tags: android, ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal SDK in Android and iOS app.

In Android app i can see there is a option to Login with PIN, But in iOS i see weird behaviour,when i run the app in Simulator i can see Login with PIN option, but when i run it on device i cant see this option.

I want both Android and iOS app to have behave exactly same.

So in Android is there a way that we can disable the "Login with PIN" feature from paypal login screen ?

otherwise am i missing anything in my iOS paypal implementation, and because of that its not showing "Login with PIN" feature from paypal login screen ?

Comment: Dave from PayPal here. To what Language and Region is your iOS device set? The ability to log into a PayPal account with phone and PIN is restricted to certain countries.

Comment: @DaveGoldman Hello Dave, thanks We are in INDIA, But "Login with PIN" is shown in Android app

Comment: @DaveGoldman Can you also please point me to Docs of "Login with PIN" as to check how it works ?

Comment: @DaveGoldman Ok after me changing the region to UK it shows "Login with PIN" option, is there any way to disable that ? in both Android and iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing (concluding?) our discussion from the comments above..

I'm not sure that the countries which support Phone/PIN login for PayPal are publicly documented. So here is the list, for both iOS and Android: Australia, Brazil, Canada, Spain, France, Great Britain, Italy, Malaysia, Singapore, United States.

This feature is built into our SDK (and into the PayPal server APIs on which our SDK relies). It is intended to perform identically on both iOS and Android. There is not a way for your app to tell the SDK to override this built-in behavior.

Comment: can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119727/encoding-special-characters-in-string#