# Encoding Special Characters in String

Tags: java, android, string, encoding, utf-8

I have a String with some special characters like this one.

```
"45” £800 77” " - > might also have some other special chars
```

Note that above string its not double quotes.

I want to display the String as it is, but for some reason its not processing and i am not able to proceed further.

What is the best way to encode this ?

I have tried the below :

```
String out = null;
        try {
            out = new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return out;
```

But it adds some special symbols to the specials chars.

I am trying to add this string in paypal payment screen , where we display item name.

Comment: can you elaborate more

Comment: @ankur-singhal i have a string with some special chars we just need to encode that properly and display as is, i am just appending this to paypal login screen,because it has some special chars its not proceeding further.

Comment: shoe me complete string, where you want to display, on UI, because with Sting as above, it i s working and displaying with syso fine

Comment: @ankur-singhal yes thats what i was trying to convey in sysout it works fine, please see my edit

Comment: where exactly is the problem, pls mention your scenarios also.

Comment: What happens when you don't do anything to the string and use it as-is?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it may helps you,

```
tv.settext(Html.fromHtml("Your Text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at something like [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from Apache Commons

Comment: I tried commons-lang lib it adds some special chars to it, its for escaping and not for encoding.